# functions, point not on graph of function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: Figure 2.2]

From the text book:

> Suppose $c=f(z)$ and $z=f(x)$. What is $x$?

No clue what is going on here. I have the solutions manual and I still don't understand. What type of problem is this? What would I study to learn about finding points not on the graph of a function?

Comment: I don't understand what help do you exactly need - "What is $x$" ??. All I can say is that if $c=f(z)$ and $z=f(x)$, then $c = f[f(x)]$, and because it is the vertical intercept it can also be noted as $c_y = f[f(0)]$. Otherwise, from general observance, it looks similar to a cubic (it has a POI) or other higher degree polynomial (ie. degree >= 3).

Comment: Do you see where the function attains the value $c$? For what input to the function would the output be $c$? They are calling that input value $z$. Now, for what input to the function would the ***output*** be $z$. They are calling that $x$ (which is a poor choice, since they've labeled the graph $f(x)$).

Comment: Can't read your diagram. The qstn gives two equations; sub the second into the first; this is called function composition; the input of the composed function is 'x'; the output is c.

Comment: You're not finding points ***not*** on the graph. You're finding points ***on*** the graph. This question is about how to interpret the graph of a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $. You would learn about it in any standard calculus textbook, or presumably any standard precalculus textbook as well (I assume. I've never read a precalculus textbook).

Comment: $f(0) = c$, $f(h) = 0$ so $f(f(h)) = c$, $x = h$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is very poorly formulated for someone just learning these ideas, because the graph-diagram has $f(x)$ shown, so presumably here $x$ is a variable, but in the equation $z = f(x)$ the letters $x$ and $z$ stand for specific numbers.

**Revised Question:** Suppose $p$ and $q$ are numbers such that $c = f(p)$ and $p = f(q).$ What is the value of $q$?

**Solution/Explanation:** The equation $c = f(p)$ means that the point $(p,c)$ is on the graph. From the graph-diagram, there is only one point on the graph that has $y$-coordinate equal to $c,$ namely the point $(0,c)$ on the $y$-axis. Since there is only one possible such point (by inspection of the graph), the only possible value for $p$ is $0.$ Thus, we know that $p = 0.$ Since $p = 0,$ it follows that the other equation — $p = f(q)$ — is $0 = f(q).$ This last equation means that the point $(q,0)$ is on the graph. From the graph-diagram, there is only one point on the graph that has $y$-coordinate equal to $0,$ namely the point $(h,0)$ on the $x$-axis. Since there is only one possible such point (by inspection of the graph), the only possible value for $q$ is $h.$ Thus, we know that $q = h.$